# Returning True or False (1 or 0) by checking if all values or no values exist in an array

Tags: sql, sql-server

Goal: Return true or false from a query that takes a list. If an item in the list does not exist, then I want to return false. If they all exist, I want to return true.

What I have (a variant of):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, sku
FROM items as items
WHERE items.sku IN ('a','b','c','doesntexist');
```

Any guidance would be great. This is for MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the count of the number of variables / items in your list and just check that against your items table.

```
if (select count(distinct sku) from items where sku IN ('a','b','c','doesntexist')) = 4
select 'True'
else
select 'False'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list apriori, you could the number of distinct items that match against it, and then use a `case` against it:

```
SELECT   id, CASE COUNT(DISTINCT sku) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS all_exists
FROM     items 
WHERE    sku IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'doesntexist') -- 4 items in the IN list:
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This works but I need the list can be any length, is there a way for me to set the array into a Declare variable and read the length?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a String-Split function on your item array so that you can then do either an OUTER JOIN or EXISTS() query to see if there are any members of the table returned by the String-Split that don't have a matching item in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select IIF(count(*) = 4, 'true', 'false') from items where item in ('a','b','c','doesntexist');
```